# How to know if specific set of character is present or not in regexp in python?

Tags: python

In python I want to make temperature converter which automatically recognize which temperature value is given and convert into other.
I need to know if some specific set of character is present or not by using re module.

my code is here

```py
import re
dataset=r'\d+\°?\s+?[CFK]{1}'
ob=re.compile(dataset)
matched=ob.match('15°C')
print(matched)
```

on the second line I want to know if C , F , K any is given that must occur one time only.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not match `'15°C'` because you specified that at least one white space character must appear after `°` (`\s+`). Below will match for `'15°C'` or `'15° C'`:

```
dataset=r'\d+\°?\s?[CFK]{1}'
```

To ensure that `C`, `F`, `K` appears only once you can try this one:

```
dataset=r'\d+\°?\s?[CFK]{1}[^CFK]*'
```

Comment: so I want to check if `C`,`F`,`K` appears only once or none how to check it?